# Android VIEW intent with content Uri

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent

I am creating a App, which should save reference documents, saved on the device.
I am receiving the content URI for these documents in the following way:

```
private void selectDocument() {
    Intent chooseFile;
    chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    chooseFile.setType("*/*");
    if (chooseFile.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
        startActivityForResult(chooseFile, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE) {

        try {
            binding.txtLink.setText(URLDecoder.decode(data.getDataString(),"UTF-8"));
            binding.btnLink.setTag(false);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

after displaying the url to the user, he should be able to open the document.

And i am not really sure how to do that, since I only get the contentURI.
What i am currently trying is this:

```
    private void openDocument() {
    String file = binding.txtLink.getText().toString();
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    Intent intent;

    String extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(file));

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(binding.root, "Keine Anwendung zum öffnen der Datei installiert", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

This already opens the correct App, but they can't find the files.

What would i need to do, to enable this behavior?
Or do i have to copy the files to my app directory and open them from there?

Comment: `"I am receiving the content URI"` - you got the `Uri`, so use it in `intent.setData`

Comment: Then I am getting this error: Permission Denial: `Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{e1e7eb8 27746:com.google.android.apps.photos/u0a151} (pid=27746, uid=10151) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs`

Comment: so use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` action

Comment: But then only a Filepicker opens up, but not the selected document.